# Approximation numbers of a nuclear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $T: H \rightarrow H'$ be a nuclear operator on Hilbert spaces. Hence it will have a representation $$T= \sum \lambda_n x_n^* \otimes y_n,$$ with $|| \lambda ||_1 < \infty$ and $ ||x_n^*|| = ||y_n||=1.  $ Let $a=(a_n)$ be the sequence of approximation numbers of $T$, $$ a_n:= \inf \{ ||T-T_n || : T_n \in \mathcal{L}(H,H') , \   \textrm{rank} (T_n) < n \}. $$

I am trying to prove that such sequence verifies that $$ \boxed{||a||_1 < \infty .}$$ I know that this can be done by keeping in mind that the approximation numbers are the singular values, so this calc can be done through spectral theory. But I was wondering if it could be proved more directly.

Comment: Your definition of $a_n$ does not depend on $n$. Also, I assume you are missing a minimum?

Comment: @Bananach Oh I am trully sorry. Of course I typed wrongly, it is as you pointed out. Now it is corrected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So next question,  why would you think you should result holds?  I am pretty sure that $\lambda_n=1/n^2$ and $ x_n=y_n $ an ONB constitutes a counter example

Comment: @Bananach In Hilbert spaces it actually holds. In Spectral Theory it is proved that nuclear operators are the  Schatten - Von Neumann 1-class, i.o.w., the sequence of singular values of the operator is in $l_1$. But, on the other hand, it can be proved that for a compact operator (e.g. a nuclear operator) the singular values are the approximation numbers, so $\sum_n a_n < \infty$.

Comment: I see, you are right.  for some reason I was thinking of the Hilbert Schmidt norm instead of the plain operator norm